# $0 \leq C + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)^n} $ ,where $C = 1.036055393...$ is the best possible constant.

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

How to prove that for all real $x$ we have :

$$0 \leq f(x) = C + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)^n} $$

Where $C = 1.036055393\ldots$ is the best possible constant.

For background see also :

[Solve for $m(t)$ in the integral transform $\int_0^1(1-t^n) m(t) dt=\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}} $ for $n>0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4800097/solve-for-mt-in-the-integral-transform-int-011-tn-mt-dt-fracn1)

where this originates from.

Also

[Conjecture about $ f(x,v) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty {x^n \over t(v n) } > 0 $ for all real $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802259/conjecture-about-fx-v-1-sum-n-1-infty-xn-over-tv-n-0-for)

is within the same spirit.

Related and another possible way to show this might be similar to this here :

[Is $ f(x,v) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^n \over \Gamma(v n +1) } > 0 $ for all real $x$ and $0<v<1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440852/is-fx-v-sum-n-0-infty-xn-over-gammav-n-1-0-for-all-real?rq=1)

I assume $C$ has no closed form btw.

***edit***

Not essential but beyond a comment perhaps :

A similar conjecture

How to prove that for all real $x$ we have :

$$0 \leq f(x) = A + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)^{\frac{n}{2}}} $$

Where $A= 1$ is the best possible constant.

***edit 2***

Notice

$$G(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)^n} $$

can be analysed with the integral transform from the first link.

$1/(n+1)^n$ at $n = 1$ gives us coefficient $1/2$.

So in order to make use of the integral transform we need

the empty product ($=1$) for the first coefficient.

So we get

$$H(x) = C_H +  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{2 x^n}{(n+1)^n} $$

and if

$$\int_0^1(1-t^n) m_h(t) dt=\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}} $$
for $n>0$ has a solution with $m_h(t)$ being positive for $0<t<1$

Then

$$H(x) = 1 +  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{2 x^n}{(n+1)^n} > 0$$

Is true and therefore

$$H(x)/2 = 1/2 +  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)^n} > 0$$

However we know this is NOT TRUE.

$$C = 1.036055393... >> 1/2$$

So the integral transformation can not be done as above.

Nevertheless we seem to get

$$0 \leq f(x) = C + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)^n} $$

(the subject and question here to solve )

and also

$$ \lim_{x \to -\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)^n} = -1$$

So we are missing something.

---

Comment: Btw I conjecture that $ x = -9,252258...$ gives the lowest possible value for $C + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)^n}$ and no other real $x$ does achieve this minimum. So in other words I conjecture $C + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)^n} = 0$ has only 1 real solution : $ x = -9.252258...$.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili good question. Notice I said the constant was the best possible, so we get arbitrarily close to 0. Infinitesimally if you want. So I guess its is a bit of notation abuse maybe. Does that help ?

Comment: @LorenzoPompili a smaller value of C does not satisfy the requirement.
For instance if C was 1 then $f(-9.25)$ is around -$0.03$

Comment: Interestingly, it appears that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{(n+1)^n} = -1$$ If one could prove this fact, the existence of $C$ would be deduced immediately.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe that conjecture was already made in the links given !

Comment: @mick as a suggestion, I think the question would be more clear and of immediate comprehension if you simply ask how to prove that the power series G
 is bounded from below by a constant independent of x
 (it is equivalent to what you are asking, right?). I am saying that because you are formulating the question in terms of $f$, which is not yet rigorously defined as the constant $C$ itself is not yet proved to exist (or, say, it is not clear whether it is a finite number). It is also good to remark that the radius of convergence of the power series is infinite, for context.

Answer (score 3):

I shall derive the asymptotics of this function as $x\to\pm\infty$. Since
$$
\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^n }} = \frac{1}{{(n - 1)!}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {t^{n - 1} {\rm e}^{ - (n + 1)t} {\rm d}t} ,
$$
we immediately obtain
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( \pm x)^n }}{{(n + 1)^n }}}  =  \pm x\int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp ( - x( \mp t{\rm e}^{ - t} )){\rm e}^{ - 2t} {\rm d}t} 
$$
for $x>0$. With the upper sign, there is a sole, simple saddle point on the path of integration at $t=1$. Consequently, by the [saddle point method](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.4.iv)
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{x^n }}{{(n + 1)^n }}}  \sim \sqrt {\frac{{2\pi }}{{{\rm e}^{\rm 3} }}} x^{1/2} \exp (x/{\rm e})
$$
as $x\to+\infty$. With the lower sign, we split the path of integration at $t=1$, and perform the change of variables $t =  - W_0 ( - s), - W_1 ( - s)$ using two real branches of the [Lambert-$W$ function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13). Thus,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - x)^n }}{{(n + 1)^n }}}  =  - x\int_0^{1/{\rm e}} {{\mathop{\rm e}\nolimits} ^{ - xs} \left( {\frac{{{\rm e}^{W_0 ( - s)} }}{{1 + W_0 ( - s)}} - \frac{{{\rm e}^{W_1 ( - s)} }}{{1 + W_1 ( - s)}}} \right){\rm d}s} 
$$
for $x>0$. By [$(4.13.5)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13.E5) and [$(4.13.11)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13.E11)
$$
\frac{{{\rm e}^{W_0 ( - s)} }}{{1 + W_0 ( - s)}} - \frac{{{\rm e}^{W_1 ( - s)} }}{{1 + W_1 ( - s)}} = 1 + \mathcal{O}(s)
$$
as $s\to 0^+$, and by [$(4.13.6)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13.E6)
$$
\frac{{{\rm e}^{W_0 ( - s)} }}{{1 + W_0 ( - s)}} - \frac{{{\rm e}^{W_1 ( - s)} }}{{1 + W_1 ( - s)}} \sim \frac{{\rm 1}}{{{\rm e}\sqrt {2(1 - {\rm e}s)} }}
$$
as $s\to 1/\mathrm{e}^-$. Hence,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - x)^n }}{{(n + 1)^n }}} =  - 1+\mathcal{O}(x^{-1})
$$
as $x\to+\infty$. The existence of $C>0$ follows from this asymptotics.

Comment: This is impressive. But very short.
How did you find the first two results ? 

Also : is the value C expressible as an integral ?

+1 already :)

Comment: First one: perform the change of integration variables from $t$ to $s$ via $s=(n+1)t$ and then use the Euler integral for the gamma function. Second: introduce the integral in the sum, interchange the order of summation and integration, use the Maclaurin series of the exponential function. I cannot see a way to express $C$ as an integral.